# camelot python append row to previous row

Tags: python, python-camelot

i am using camelot to extract a table from pdf document. The table has Date,Description,Credit,Debit and Balance Fields. The description field sometimes has rows that are long, extending to the next row. if I use camelot, it prints the rows as shown below:

```
 Transaction Date                                 Description       Debit        Credit     Balance
2         01/11/2020                                     BAL B/F                38,485.30  38,485.30
3         02/11/2020                                               20,000.00                18,485.30
4                                            MB X WITHDRAWAL
5                     Ref. MP:V TO X NO:5MP:V TO
6                                               X NO:9
7         04/11/2020                         MB X WITHDRAWAL   20,000.00                98,485.30
8                     Ref. MP:V TO X NO:40MP:V TO
9                                               X NO:47
10        05/11/2020                         MB X WITHDRAWAL   80,000.00                18,485.30
```

I would like the table to appear in such a way that the rows under "Description" field, are combined to form one row if they extend to the next row e.g:

```
Transaction Date                                 Description           Debit        Credit     Balance
2  01/11/2020                                     BAL B/F                           38,485.30  38,485.30
3  02/11/2020    MB X WITHDRAWAL Ref. MP:V TO X NO:5MP:V TO X NO:9    20,000.00                18,485.30
```

This is my code:

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf('D:\\test.pdf', flavor='stream', edge_tol=500)
print(tables[0].df)
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please post the PDF (or part of it) in order to undestand better your question...

Comment: unfortunately i can't post the pdf, it has sensitive data

Comment: I understand you, but without the original file (a page is enough) it is difficult to help you.
As often in Camelot, it is tweaking parameters stuff.